# Qutation Marks within VBA for IF statement

Tags: excel, vba, double-quotes

I am trying to copy an `IF` formula in a range, but my issue, much like others, comes from the double quotes. I currently have `CHR(34)` to indicate I want the double quote, but my VBA error is `Expected end of line.`

How I need it to appear as a formula:

```
=IF(D2=team,"",IF(D2=on," - Type1",IF(OR(D2=lr,D2=sn),"*"," - Type3")))
```

`team, on, lr, sign` are variables that refer to strings.

```
Range()= "=IF(D2=" & team & ", "&Chr(34)&Chr(34)&",IF(D2=" & on & ","&Chr(34)&" - Type1"&Chr(34)&",IF(OR(D2=" &lr& ",D2=" &sn& "),"&Chr(34)&"*"&Chr(34)&","&Chr(34)&" - Type3"& Chr(34)&")))"
```

It presents the error in the second instance of `D2` in the `OR` statement

Comment: I have it in my head that you need spaces to separate the `&`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following should work as you expect it to, I simply changed the variable name from `on` to `oni` as I don't think you can have a variable named `on` also I separated the &'s with spaces:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(D2=" & team & ", " & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ",IF(D2="" & oni & ""," & Chr(34) & " - Type1" & Chr(34) & ",IF(OR(D2=" & lr & ",D2=" & sn & ")," & Chr(34) & "*" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & " - Type3" & Chr(34) & ")))"
```